# iOS Swift - How to hide a UIView element and claim the space?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, hide, hidden

I'm new to iOS coming from Android background.

When applying .hidden = true to a UIView, it is hidden however it still takes its space. Is there a way to claim this space when the view is gone (similar to setVisibility(View.GONE) in Android?

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

If you are targeting iOS 9 or later, you can use a `UIStackView` to accomplish this automatically (similar to `LinearLayout` on Android). When you set a view that is contained in a UIStackView to hidden, the remaining views will shift to reclaim the space.

You can animate the shift by setting `view.hidden = true` inside of an animation block by using

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(_:delay:options:animations:completion:)
```

or the like.

If you are targeting iOS versions lower than 9 (where `UIStackView` is not supported), you have to manually update your auto layout constraints whenever you hide or show the view.

For example, say you have 3 views stacked on top of each other, called view1, view2, and view3, you first remove view2 and view3's top constraints by calling

```
view2TopConstraint.active = false
view3TopConstraint.active = false
```

and then add a top constraint on view3 that is pinned to the bottom of view1

```
let newView2TopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view3, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view1, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
newView2TopConstraint.active = true
```

There are many ways to achieve this. This is just one example.

Comment: If i could give you +2 I would, trust me :) Thank you this solved my problem.

Comment: can we do this without using stackview ?

Answer (score -2):

There's no visibility setting. But you can just set the alpha to 0

Comment: This does not claim the space, it will still take up space